# MySql - Join self to determine time in state

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (let's call it WorkflowLog) whose records are log records about a workflow processor.
The workflow processor moves records in various tables (Table1, Table2, etc) thru defined flowchart states.  Each state has a number.
The WorkflowLog records are as follows:

```
|   ID   |      TimeStamp       | TableN  | RecordId | Action       | OldState | NewState |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1  | 2016-09-16 15:50:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |    0     |   10     |
|     2  | 2016-09-16 15:50:00  | Table1  | 21       | Other Info   |    0     |   10     |
|     3  | 2016-09-16 15:55:00  | Table2  | 21       | State Change |    0     |   10     |
|     4  | 2016-09-16 15:57:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |   10     |   20     |
|     5  | 2016-09-16 15:58:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |   20     |   30     |
|     6  | 2016-09-16 15:59:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |   30     |   20     |
|     7  | 2016-09-16 16:00:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |   20     |   30     |
|     8  | 2016-09-16 16:01:00  | Table1  | 52       | State Change |    0     |   10     |
|     9  | 2016-09-16 16:02:00  | Table1  | 21       | State Change |   30     |  999     |
|    10  | 2016-09-16 16:03:00  | Table3  | 25       | State Change |    0     |   10     |
```

I would like to determine the amount of time spent in each table state.  Please NOTE that the workflow can loop so the record can be in state 20 (or any state) multiple times.

My first try was:

```
select
    DFT1.ID as DFT1_Id,
    DFT2.ID as DFT2_Id,
    DFT1.TableN as TableName,
    DFT1.RecordId as RecordId,
    DFT1.OldState as State,
    DFT2.Timestamp as EntryTime,
    DFT1.TimeStamp as ExitTime,
    TIMEDIFF(DFT1.TimeStamp, DFT2.Timestamp) as TimeInState
from WorkflowLog DFT1
    inner join WorkflowLog DFT2
        ON DFT1.TableN=DFT2.TableN AND
            DFT1.RecordId=DFT2.RecordId AND
            DFT1.`Action`='State Change' AND
            DFT2.`Action`='State Change' AND
            DFT1.OldState=DFT2.NewState
Order BY DFT1_Id
```

But this does not handle when a record loops in the workflow (as record 6 captures).  It seems that I have to do something similar to the above **BUT only match the previous most recent**.
I am at a loss on how to do that.

Ultimately what I want is an output like:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | TableN | RecId | State | EntryTime           | ExitTime            | TimeInState |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  4  |  1  | Table1 | 21    |  10   | 2016-09-16 15:50:00 | 2016-09-16 15:57:00 |  00:07:00   |
|  5  |  4  | Table1 | 21    |  20   | 2016-09-16 15:57:00 | 2016-09-16 15:58:00 |  00:01:00   |
|  6  |  5  | Table1 | 21    |  30   | 2016-09-16 15:58:00 | 2016-09-16 15:59:00 |  00:01:00   |
|  7  |  6  | Table1 | 21    |  20   | 2016-09-16 15:59:00 | 2016-09-16 16:00:00 |  00:01:00   |
|  9  |  7  | Table1 | 21    |  30   | 2016-09-16 16:00:00 | 2016-09-16 16:02:00 |  00:02:00   |
ETC ...
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested I have added an [SqlFiddle for the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9541a/5) with my first try SQL.
There are extra matches in the Result set due to Table1 record 21 going thru state 20 and 30 twice.  Here are my comments about the SqlFiddle result set:

```
| ID | ID | My Comment                                    |
|  4 |  1 |  Good                                         |
|  5 |  6 |  Not Good - Matched with Future record        |
|  5 |  4 |  Good                                         |
|  6 |  7 |  Not Good - Matched with Future record        |
|  6 |  5 |  Good                                         |
|  7 |  6 |  Good                                         |
|  7 |  4 |  Not Good - Match to First time thru state 20 |
|  9 |  5 |  Not Good - Match to First time thru state 30 |
|  9 |  7 |  Good                                         |
```

Comment: create a sqlfiddle for a dataload

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7a74/1 - needs the Dept table adding.

Comment: @Drew -- Created SQL Fiddle as suggested [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9541a/5) Also edited the post to add the fiddle and some comments about it.

Comment: @RyanVincent -- In my SqlFiddle, i corrected the output error by formatting the timediff().  I think it was from some JDBC issue.  See my comment above or the Edited post for my sqlfiddle.